# Generate a map of list element indices using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I want to take a `List`, and generate a `Dictionary` which maps each element to its index in the `List`. I can do this like so, for a `List<string>`:

```
var myList = new List<string>{ /* populate list */ };
var orderMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var element in myList)
{
    orderMap[element] = myList.IndexOf(element);
}
```

Basically, I want to take a list like:

```
Apple
Banana
Orange
```

And return a map showing indices:

```
Apple -> 0
Banana -> 1
Orange -> 2
```

How can I do this with Linq? I think something like this should work:

```
orderMap = myList.Select( x => /* return a key value pair mapping x to myList.IndexOf(x) */ );
```

But I can't figure out the right syntax for it. Besides, can you refer to the list itself in the delegate used for `Select`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While you *can* refer to the list within the delegate, it's not generally a good idea. You really want to use the overload of `Select` which provides the index as well as the value:

```
var dictionary = list.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                     .ToDictionary(p => p.value, p => p.index);
```

Note that this will throw an exception if you have any duplicate elements.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) extension method:

```
int index = 0; 
orderMap = myList.ToDictionary(x => x, x => index++);
```

Comment: Ick, side-effects in a selector? No thanks :) I realize that in this case it's using immediate evaluation, and *will* work - but it's still something I'd personally avoid.

Comment: This selects index as key but OP wants the string to be key.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know it's not the cleanest solution. I always seem to forget that useful overload of `Select` :) @L.B Thanks, fixed that. misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this overload of `ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx). It takes to functions to convert the input element into a Key and a Value.

e.g.

```
var myList = new List<string>{ /* populate list */ };
var orderMap = myList.ToDictionary(x => myList.IndexOf(x), x => x);
```

However, one problem with this is if the elements of `myList` aren't unique.

Comment: This will run in O(n^2 * log(n)), whereas the two other answers run in O(n * log(n)), since `IndexOf()` will scan the list.